# Custom field not showing on order details (admin)

Tags: admin, attributes, customer, magento-1, address

I created three new fields in the register address, I need to show them in the order details. I tried adding them going:

*System > Customers > Settings > Templates Address*

And added the fields with the same name that is in the database. Here's an example of how I tried:

```
{{number_address}}
{{depend number_address}}{{var number_address}}{{/depend}}
{{if number_address}}{{var number_address}},  {{/if}}
```

Comment: Check this third party extensions, the fields you create are shown on the backend and order page...http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/advance-custom-registration-form-fields-customer-attributes.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've read this tutorial: http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/how_to_add_custom_field_in_billing_and_shipping_address_in_frontend_and_backend

Check the attribute creation:

```
foreach ($attributes as $attributeCode => $data) {
    $attribute = $eavConfig->getAttribute('customer_address', $attributeCode);
    $attribute->setWebsite($store->getWebsite());
    $attribute->addData($data);
        $usedInForms = array(
            'adminhtml_customer_address',
            'customer_address_edit',
            'customer_register_address'
        );
        $attribute->setData('used_in_forms', $usedInForms);
    $attribute->save();
}
```

See the `$usedInForms` array ? Try to insert the handles of order details pages there.

It may not suffice, but I think it's necessary.

Comment: Thanks for reply Niloct. I used this... I found a bug now, when I go into the details of the purchase> Edit Billing Address or Edit Shipping Address appears those fields that I created, but empty. 

But when I go to Customers > Manage Customers > Choose an Customer > Addresses fields appear filled.

Comment: If I fill them by admin didn't work too.

Comment: I found my error, I haven't added the columns in the table sales_flat_order_address. Thanks to everyone.

Comment: Great insight =) You're welcome.